# sort data in 2 prototype cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

If I have 2 prototype cells and each row has a timestamp. Is it possible to sort cells based on the timestamp of their rows? or second cell will be always under the first one? Example below. This is general question, so I want to know in which direction should I look

```
Prototype cell 1
Prototype cell 2
Prototype cell 2
Prototype cell 1
```

**Update with some code**

Basically I have first prototype cell which I already sorted by timestamp and it's working fine.

```
func attemptReloadOfTable() {
    self.messages.sort(by: {$0.timestamp < $1.timestamp})
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Later I added another prototype cell which provide date which should be sorted within first prototype cell and the second one. Second prototype cell also has timestamp and I'm not sure how to mix them.

Comment: you need to sort your datasource array of timestamps and then will be ordered your cells in the tableView, can you provide some code to try help you?

Comment: @ReinierMelian thank you for your reply. Just updated my question with more details, not sure if it will be clear for you. Let me know please.

Comment: Are you using the same datasource array for both cells types?

Comment: @ReinierMelian different datasource. Should it be the same?

Comment: Of course use the same datasource or mix both datasource arrays and sort it and should work properly

Comment: @ReinierMelian thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Your welcome @Sargot, anyway you almost have it in first place, good luck and happy coding!